# Draw straight line/arrow from between two shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a straight arrow from one shape to another, two rectangles precisely. I have an MWE below, but the arrow from rectangle B meets rectangle A at an angle instead of at 90 degrees.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw,shape=rectangle,minimum width=3.5em,text width=1.7cm,align=center,minimum height=1.2cm, node distance=3cm]

\node[block] (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[block,right of=A] (B) {B};
\draw[->] ([yshift=-2em] B) -- ([yshift=-2em] A);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Do you really want a moved down arrow? Instead of simply `\draw[->] (B)--(A);`?

Comment: @Sigur Why doesn't it work, though?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, I really do want a moved down arrow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This looks like a bug for me.**

In a strange way if we use `([transform] A)` when `A` is a node, the anchor to, or from, `A` is calculated before the transformation, and the node `A` is transformed only afterwards.

In your example :

1. the anchor to `A` is calculated, and not to `([yshift=-2em] A)`, from the shifted `B` (or more precisely from `([yshift=-2em] B.center)`);
2. the anchor from `B` is calculated, not from `([yshift=-2em] B)`, to the calculated anchor of `A`.

Here is an illustration of this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  block/.style = {draw, minimum width=1.7cm, minimum height=1.2cm, node distance=3cm},
  down/.style={yshift=-7em}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % "almost" the original code
    \node[block] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[block,right of=A] (B) {B};
    \draw[->] ([down] B) -- ([down] A)  -- ([down] B);

    % illustration of the anchor calculation
    \begin{scope}[red]
      \node[block] (A2) at ([down] A) {A2};
      \node[block] (B2) at ([down] B) {B2};
      \draw[->] (B2) -- (A);
    \end{scope}

    % and more examples
    \begin{scope}[blue]
      \draw[->] ([down] B) -- ([down] A.east);
      \draw[->] ([down] B.west) -- ([down] A);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**In conclusion :** We can't transform nodes like this, only "real" coordinates are transformed.

**Workaround:** You can use `transform canvas` to do your shifts like this :

```
    \begin{scope}[ transform canvas={yshift=-2em}]
      \draw[->] (B) -- (A);
    \end{scope}
```

In your particular MWE a workaround will be also to specify the anchors like this :

```
\draw[->] ([yshift=-2em] B.west) -- ([yshift=-2em] A.east);
```

**UPDATE:** Actually `([transformed] A)` looks to have a "double nature" : as a coordinate it is the same as `([transformed] A.center)` and as a node it is the same as `(A)`. Here is one example that shows this "double behavior" of coordinate transformed nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  block/.style = {draw,minimum width=1.7cm, minimum height=1.2cm, node distance=3cm}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[block, circle] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[block,right of=A] (B) {B};

    % ([yshift=-2em] A) behaves like the node (A)
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,360}
        \draw[blue, ->] (\i:2) -- ([yshift=-2em] A);

    % ([rotate=\i]B) behaves like the point ([rotate=\i]B.center) to calculate the anchor of (A)
    % and then behaves like the node (B) when we draw from it.
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,360}
      \draw[red,->] ([rotate=\i]B) -- (A);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful and I agree it looks like a bug. However, I'm finding it rather difficult to follow. I reworded a little bit at the top, where I was confident that I understood your intended meaning (but obviously you should roll back if not). But I get a bit lost after that. I find the part where you offer a workaround and then add a note and conclusion especially confusing. Is the note supporting the workaround? Or are you saying the workaround doesn't work? Apologies for my slowness!

Comment: @cfr thanks for your edit (and happy new year)! I removed the note and merged it with the "update" (I have updated this answer more then 10 times :(). And I moved the conclusion before the workaround. Is like this more readable ? If not, feel free to edit it.

Comment: (+1) That seems much clearer to me now. It is complex because the subject matter is complex, but it flows a lot more logically - especially switching the workaround and the conclusion. That makes much better sense to me now.

Comment: This is really weird, isn't it? It seems like a bug, but it is surprising to me that people have not triggered it before, if so.

Comment: @cfr personally I have never used `([transform] A)` with a node `A` before this example. For me this was a syntax for coordinates only ...

Comment: @cfr We did. But I don't think this is a bug, it's how it is designed http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174098/3235

Comment: @percusse ?? You did what?

Comment: @cfr We triggered it. You need to use `A.center`, `B.center` but not `A,B` if you want to add transformations on the path. Because the former ones are coordinates, the latter ones are node names. And transformations apply on coordinates.

Comment: @percusse Sorry I can't understand what you say. You point to answer that is not using `([transform] Node)` syntax. Then you say "We did. We triggered it.", what ? Did you use the syntax `([transform] Node)` somewhere ? And if yes, why ? And if `([transform] Node)` is supposed to be equivalent to `([transform] Node.center)` then there is a bug, because it is not equivalent, as we can see in the example.

Comment: In the link above, you can see that node named referrals don't satisfy transformations. So in that sense, it is known that you can't simply apply path transformations to nodes and when you add `transform shape` it is context dependent. `([transform] node)` is not equivalent. It is meant for `([transform]<coord>)`. In this original case for example, it picks up whatever it has in the coordinate buffer namely the north west corner of `B` as the coord and goes down -2em. Then for `A` I don't know :)

Comment: Actually I don't know about B either I guess.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why this is necessary, but a workaround might be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [block/.style={
      draw,
      shape=rectangle,
      minimum width=3.5em,
      text width=1.7cm,
      align=center,
      minimum height=1.2cm,
      node distance=3cm}
    ]

    \node[block] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[block, right=of A] (B) {B};% new syntax is recommended using the positioning library
    \draw[->] (B) -- (A);% for comparison only
    \draw[->] (B.west) +(0,-1em) coordinate (b1) -- (A.east |- b1);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: lowered arrow]

Comment: You don't understand why what is necessary?

Comment: @iab I don't understand why your code doesn't work.

Comment: @cfr What if I want to bidirectional arrow between two boxes

Comment: @new_born Use `<->` rather than `->` or `<-`?

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution where you have to choose the dimensions of the two boxes and the length of the arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand*\pictureWidth{\fpeval{\widthA+\arrowLength+\widthB}}
\newcommand*\pictureHeight{\fpeval{max(\heightA,\heightB)}}

\begin{document}

% dimensions of the first box
\def\widthA{2}
\def\heightA{1}
% length of the arrow
\def\arrowLength{2}
% dimensions of the second box
\def\widthB{2.5}
\def\heightB{1.5}
% the picture
\begin{pspicture}(\pictureWidth,\pictureHeight)
  \psframe(0,0)(\widthA,\heightA)
  \rput(\fpeval{\widthA/2},\fpeval{\heightA/2}){A}
  \psline{->}%
    (\fpeval{\widthA+\arrowLength},\fpeval{4/15*(\heightA+\heightB)/2})%
    (\widthA,\fpeval{4/15*(\heightA+\heightB)/2})
  \psframe(\fpeval{\widthA+\arrowLength},0)(\fpeval{\widthA+\arrowLength+\widthB},\heightB)
  \rput(\fpeval{\widthA+\arrowLength+\widthB/2},\fpeval{\heightB/2}){B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]