# Node placement, cycle, and scaling

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the simplest case, I have a square whose sides shall be labelled. Then I shift the square, either by manually adding an offset to the x- or y-coordinate of each point or using `xshift` and `yshift`. Everything works just fine as long as I specify the path through five points: The four corners plus the starting point, thus the first corner again.

If I use `cycle` instead of passing the first coordinate again, something very weird happens to the last label. Especially once I rescale the `tikzpicture`...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% Not helping: every node/.style={scale=2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  % Works
  \draw
  (0,0) -- node[left] {A0}
  (0,1) -- node[above] {B0}
  (1,1) -- node[right] {C0}
  (1,0) -- node[below] {D0}
  cycle;

  % Works
  \draw
  (2,0) -- node[left] {A2}
  (2,1) -- node[above] {B2}
  (2+1,1) -- node[right] {C2}
  (2+1,0) -- node[below] {D2}
  (2,0);

  % Does not work (as long as scale!=1)
  \draw
  (4,0) -- node[left] {A4}
  (4,1) -- node[above] {B4}
  (4+1,1) -- node[right] {C4}
  (4+1,0) -- node[below] {D4}
  cycle;

  % This works
  \draw[yshift=-2cm]
  (0,0) -- node[left] {A6}
  (0,1) -- node[above] {B6}
  (1,1) -- node[right] {C6}
  (1,0) -- node[below] {D6}
  (0,0);

  % Never works (it's really "cycle" that's to blame here)
  \draw[yshift=-2cm, xshift=2cm]
  (0,0) -- node[left] {A8}
  (0,1) -- node[above] {B8}
  (1,1) -- node[right] {C8}
  (1,0) -- node[below] {D8}
  cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering]

Comment: I imagine you know that similar squares can be done with `\node[draw, minimum size=1cm, label=90:B0, label=0:C0, label=180:A0, label=270:D0, transform shape] at (1,1) {};`. `transform shape` is necessary to apply scale changes to nodes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm afraid that does not help me, since I'm interested in more general shapes than squares. I chose a square just for this MWE.

Comment: Actually none of them are working because `-- node{}` syntax is wrong. Try to put them somewhere not on the midway. The related concept is **timer** that you can read about in the manual. Hence, `(coord) -- (coord) node {}` is how the node placement timer is done. Also after cycle you can't do any timer stuff as the path is finalized so it won't work.

Comment: @percusse Could you precise, please. For me this looks more like a bug. First, this works without transformations, second, there is no error message. And if the path is finalized with cycle, why we can put `...-- cycle -- (coordinates) --...` ? Or at least there is a missing note in the manual "do not place nodes after cycle" ;)

Comment: This looks like a [node transformation inconsistency](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220317/9335). I can't understand this example `\tikz\draw[xshift=2cm] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle node{x} -- (0,1);`.

Comment: @Kpym I mean the pen is lifted in the same vein `(0,0) -- (1,0) (1,0) --(2,1)`

Comment: (sorry for being quiet for so long) @percusse: Are you sure the syntax `(coord) -- node {} (coord)` is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `(current subpath start) -- cycle` works. (But I'm not clear why `cycle` does not.)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

% Not helping: every node/.style={scale=2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  % Works
  \draw
  (0,0) -- node[left] {A0}
  (0,1) -- node[above] {B0}
  (1,1) -- node[right] {C0}
  (1,0) -- node[below] {D0}
  cycle;

  % Works
  \draw
  (2,0) -- node[left] {A2}
  (2,1) -- node[above] {B2}
  (2+1,1) -- node[right] {C2}
  (2+1,0) -- node[below] {D2}
  (2,0);

  % Does not work (as long as scale!=1)
  \draw
  (4,0) -- node[left] {A4}
  (4,1) -- node[above] {B4}
  (4+1,1) -- node[right] {C4}
  (4+1,0) -- node[below] {D4}
  (current subpath start) -- cycle;

  % This works
  \draw[yshift=-2cm]
  (0,0) -- node[left] {A6}
  (0,1) -- node[above] {B6}
  (1,1) -- node[right] {C6}
  (1,0) -- node[below] {D6}
  (0,0);

  % Never works (it's really "cycle" that's to blame here)
  \draw[yshift=-2cm, xshift=2cm]
  (0,0) -- node[left] {A8}
  (0,1) -- node[above] {B8}
  (1,1) -- node[right] {C8}
  (1,0) -- node[below] {D8}
  (current subpath start)
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: make nodes behave]

Comment: It would be interesting to know why `cycle` doesn't work, indeed. For the time being, this makes for a nice workaround. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @anonymous Agreed! Wish I knew!