# Problem with tikzpicture scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

If I compile this (with lualatex):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
% Declare Points
\coordinate (C) at (-0.085,0.318);
\coordinate (B) at (0.868,0.868);
\coordinate (A) at (0.868,-0.232);

% Draw EquilateralTriangle
\draw[thick] (C)
-- (B) node[midway, sloped, scale=0.5] {O}
-- (A) node[midway, sloped, scale=0.5] {O}
-- cycle node[midway, sloped, scale=0.5] {O};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get this correct result: [image]

But if I set the scale to something else, like 3, then I get: [image]

The last "O" is floating anywhere...

Is there an obvious problem in my code? Is this a bug? (If yes, is there any workaround?).

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251935/node-placement-cycle-and-scaling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply draw to `C` and then cycle. This will scale flawlessly.

*Edit:* The problem should be that `cycle` closes the current part of the path what might cause some problems if the current part is used later on.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
% Declare Points
\coordinate (C) at (-0.085,0.318);
\coordinate (B) at (0.868,0.868);
\coordinate (A) at (0.868,-0.232);

% Draw EquilateralTriangle
\draw[thick] (C)
-- (B) node[midway, sloped, scale=0.5] {O}
-- (A) node[midway, sloped, scale=0.5] {O}
-- (C) node[midway, sloped, scale=0.5] {O} -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, thanks! And so I guess this is a workaround? (note that actually when drawing to C, then it's not useful to cycle any longer to get the correct picture) And that the problem is an actual bug? (i.e. one can expect the code I posted to work)

Comment: The last cycle does make a difference. Zoom in the corner to see it.